# Win32 buffer size for read from stdin

Tags: windows, winapi, stdin

I'm trying to read data from stdin, in C++ on Windows, efficiently, which means preferably in large chunks. This can be done with:

```
ReadFile(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buf, bytestoread, &bytesread, 0);
```

or

```
read(0, buf, bytestoread);
```

But in both cases, it only works if `bytestoread` is set to a very small number e.g. 50; if set to a larger number e.g. one megabyte, the call fails with 'not enough space' error, as though the data were not going directly to the buffer I provide, but instead being copied via some internal buffer of fixed size. This is true whether the input is piped, or typed on the console.

Is Windows just limited in how large a chunk a process can read from stdin at a time? If so, what's the maximum chunk size that is guaranteed to work?

A complete program that shows the problem:

```
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <io.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char buf[1000000];

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      auto r = read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
      if (r < 0)
        perror("read");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *Windows* not limited. but this is device(to which point `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`) specific. result can be different for console, pipe, filesystem file

Comment: @RbMm Okay, so what value is guaranteed to work in all cases?

Comment: That's an unusual way to do console input, surely we all like to know what the point of that might be.  But sure, console input is buffered independently, nothing happens until you press the Enter key.  64KB is a popular limit for the console.  Surely you'll have to tinker with Get/SetConsoleMode(), with the expectation that you have to at least turn off the ENABLE_LINE_INPUT option.

Comment: @HansPassant Well it's not actually about console input; the point is, my program needs to accept potentially large chunks of data, which might be read from a file, or might be piped in; it's the latter case I'm concerned about.

Comment: really i doubt that you can got error with big buffer. what is device ? what is error/code exactly ? in general - because you allocate buffer - it size not limited.

Comment: @RbMm What you say is what I would've expected, but turns out not to be the case. Error happens with both console and piped input.

Comment: so show your code exactly with exactly ntstatus error code

Comment: How do you allocate your buffer? On the stack or on the heap? I did a little test, and if I put a large buffer on the stack my program fails (even before the call to ReadFile); but if I put the buffer on the heap, everything works OK.
Please post a minimal program that compiles and shows the problem.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven Done. As shown, produces 'read: Not enough space', but works okay if buf is reduced to 50 bytes.

Comment: @rwallace Hate to say it because it's not really helpful, but that code works for me (on Windows 7).

Comment: @RoelSchroeven *blink* You compile and run it at the console, and it accepts a line of input with no error, even with the one megabyte buffer? I'm on Windows 7 too, and I've tried with both Microsoft C++ and Clang, 32 and 64 bit, compiling as C and C++, and I get the error message in all cases.

Comment: @rwallace Indeed: one megabyte buffer, accepts a line of input without error. When I pipe a lot of data in, I get a different error because Windows still tries to write to the pipe even after it's closed. That's because we should actually be reading in a loop until we have read all data -- but that's a totally different issue. I compiled with Embarcadero C++Builder which uses a different C runtime. I'll see if I can try with Microsoft C++.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven Right, my real code does read in a loop, but I stripped that out for the minimal example. I had not expected a different runtime to make a difference given that I get the same problem with ReadFile, but I would definitely be interested in your results if you can try with Microsoft C++. Just to check, you are using the standard Windows terminal, not Powershell or one of the UNIX front ends?

Comment: @rwallace I compiled with the compiler from Visual Studio 2008 now. "echo hello | foo" works, but just "foo" now says "read: Not enough space"! Interesting. (I'm using the standard Windows terminal). Actually the same happens with my original program: just the program, without piped input, says "read: Not enough memory". Apprrently I hadn't tried that before.

Comment: Summarized a bit: when using a pipe on the command line (like "echo hello | foo" or "type bigfile | foo") everything works. But when just starting foo with the intention of typing in something, I have the same problem as you, both with C++Builder and Microsoft C++. Same thing on Linux works flawlessly. Windows kernel bug??

Comment: at first use not `read` but `ReadFile`, at second show exactly error code from`RtlGetLastNtStatus()`.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven Right, I will probably just use isatty to bail if input is not piped. Thanks!

Comment: @RoelSchroeven Hmm. The documentation does say, “The ReadFile function may fail with ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER or ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY whenever there are too many outstanding asynchronous I/O requests,” but why would that be happening here?

Comment: @RoelSchroeven Could it be: “The ReadFile function may fail with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA, which means the calling process's buffer could not be page-locked.”? Does this still occur if you the code uses a buffer aligned to the page size, static or on the heap?

Comment: @Davislor: You should probably address your comments to rwallace: he/she is the one who asked the question. I am merely a passer-by trying to help.

Comment: the OP probably not want understand source of problem, if used `read` instead `ReadFile` or `NtReadFile` and still not post ntstatus error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t say which version of the runtime and OS you use, but I cannot reproduce this problem with MSVC 19.16.27031.1 on Windows 10.  There are a few documented reasons it might fail.  From the [MSDN documentation of `ReadFile`:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile)

> Characters can be read from the console input buffer by using `ReadFile` with a handle to console input. The console mode determines the exact behavior of the `ReadFile` function. By default, the console mode is `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`, which indicates that `ReadFile` should read until it reaches a carriage return. If you press Ctrl+C, the call succeeds, but `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`. For more information, see `CreateFile`.

There’s another way you could be getting this error, relating to asynchronous I/O, but that does not seem to be the problem here.  You probably want to turn off the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` flag with [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).  The documentation also says the call could fail with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA` if the memory pages of the buffer cannot be locked.  However, you use a static buffer that should not have this problem.

If you’re reading a file on disk, and not a console stream, you might [map it to memory,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) which eliminates any intermediate buffering and loads the sections of files as needed, by the same mechanism as virtual memory.

Comment: how is `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` related to problem at all ?

Comment: @RbMm From the documentation: “By default, the console mode is ENABLE_LINE_INPUT, which indicates that ReadFile should read until it reaches a carriage return.” This might be causing a larger read to fail.

Comment: no, i not view how this can *causing a larger read to fail*. how all this related to problem

Comment: *The documentation also says the call could fail with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA if the memory pages of the buffer cannot be locked. However, you use a static buffer that should not have this problem.* this is also absolute wrong. are buffer "static" or not absolute unrelated here. all user mode buffer are pageable. problem can be if device use direct io

Comment: *Does page-aligning the buffer help?* - no

Answer (score 2):

If you try to read stdin `binary` data you need:

1. to set `_setmode( _fileno( stdin), _O_BINARY);`
2. and `fread( buf, 1, bufSize, stdin)`

And take a look at my similar solution when
app takes binary data via `stdin`, throttle speed, and
puts it out to `stdout`.

[bin_pipe_throttle](https://github.com/stepger/handy_tools/blob/use/src_apps/bin_pipe_throttle/main.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, is `stdin` not limited. It works as an endless Stream and should provide as much storage as you need. The only option I see is that the kernel you are using blocks at some point